# Jenkins java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/trilead/ssh2/crypto/Base64

Tags: jenkins

Today I update my Jenkins version from 2.151 to 2.152 (in my ec2 instance) and the first error I get is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/trilead/ssh2/crypto/Base64`

I get this error:

**Screenshot**
[image]
**This is the log:**

> ```
> org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.152.jar!/lib/layout/hasPermission.jelly:35:20: <d:invokeBody> com/trilead/ssh2/crypto/Base64
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:745)
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:289)
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:147)
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>   at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
> ...
> org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:258)
>   at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:104)
>   at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
>   at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
>   ... 108 more
> ```

Anyone have any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eric Y. Theriault has pointed out, the issue is with the old SSH Slaves plugin.

In `<jenkinsHome>/plugins` folder:

- Delete `ssh-slaves` folder
- Delete files starting with `ssh-slaves`
- Restart Jenkins
- Install latest SSH Slaves plugin (if needed).

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue -- it appeared to go away (at least so far) after upgrading to the latest Jenkins SSH Slaves plugin from 1.29 to 1.29.1.

Comment: How Can I do this?

Comment: Go to Manage Jenkins and then select Manage Plugins.  Then click Check Updates and if there is one, you'll see it, need to install, and restart Jenkins.  You can also see what is installed on the Installed tab.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't do this beacuse the UI is blocked (as you can see from screenshot).